# Safari and umbraco website

Tags: safari, umbraco

I've setup an umbraco 7.1.3 website on **http://www.rijschoolvti-ieper.be**.
The website runs fine on IE, Mozilla, Google Chrome when I enter www.rijschoolvti-ieper.be in the address bar of the browsers.

When I enter www.rijschoolvti-ieper.be in the address bar of **Safari** I get below error.

> Blockquote
>   Attempt by security transparent method 'Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(System.Object, System.EventArgs)' to access security critical method 'System.AppDomain.add_UnhandledException(System.UnhandledExceptionEventHandler)' failed.
>   Assembly 'Umbraco.Core, Version=1.0.5820.25371, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.

However, when I enter **http://rijschoolvti-ieper.be** in the addressbar of Safari the websites loads perfectly.

Perhaps it has anything to do with the trust level, but then why is the site loading in the other browsers...

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Seems more a server issue than a browser issue, I guess there's something wrong with the configuration.  
Anyway I noticed that you have ")" just after the opening of the <body> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you say, a server issue. The hoster does not provide full trust. Umbraco needs full trust.

The website you are seeing, is the old version now, without Umbraco.
I wil move to an other hostingprovider.

greetings